# Rstudio stopped working after installing SPSS R-plugin

Tags: r, spss, rstudio

I'm trying to use R through SPSS syntax (I'm using SPSS 18 on windows 7) which requires installing a special plugin: PASWStatistics_RPlugIn_1802_win32.exe. Also I had to install an older version of R(2.8.1 - required by my older version of SPSS - i like it better than the new ones). The plugin now works, R (both versions) works, but Rstudio stopped working and won't start even after uninstalling and re-installing.
Does anyone have any similar experience and could suggest a solution?

Comment: I'm not at *all* surprised that RStudio doesn't work with old versions of R, especially really old ones.  I think you'll be stuck here and have to learn to use an alternate R interface if you want to use R 2.8.  I'd say your best bet would be to talk to the SPSS tech support and see what they say.

Comment: Given what @BenBolker says, perhaps your next question should be "How can I direct Rstudio to use one of several versions of R installed on my machine?". (You could ask the same w.r.t. SPSS, but if they're *requiring* R 2.8 or less (?!?), I suspect they're less sophisticated about these things than the Rstudio crew.)

Comment: @BenBolker I believe Rstudio requires R >= 2.11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following link specifies how you can configure Rstudio to work with a specific R version you have installed:

http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/advanced/versions_of_r

Just install R 2.8 and 2.14 and let spss use one, and Rstudio another.

You are taking a risk by using old versions of spss and R (bugs that have been fixed in newer versions, decreased performance, possible incompatibility with other software e.g. R packages, missing functionality).

Comment: After much fiddling I could find no way to get Rstudio to work and tell it to chose the right version of R, while R-18 was installed. Finally I uninstalled it, re-installed Rstudio with only one version of R (2.14.1) on the machine. Now i could tell Rstudio to use this R version specifically and not as the default. And now finally i could re-install the old R version without the Rstudio exploding.

Comment: Re using old versions of SPSS - I'm stuck in version 18 because I built a huge set of macros for analysis involving right to left languages, and most of them stopped functioning (not always explicitly) when i tried to update to version 21 - I guess this one's for a different forum...

Comment: thanks for your help! and thanks to Ben Polker and Josh O'Brien too.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple versions of R installed at the same time - I have five.  The current version of Statistics, 21, goes with R2.14.  I don't know how Rstudio determines which version to use.  You might need to reset the R environment variables or your path settings.